# grails + jquery ui plugin, using custom theme

Tags: jquery-ui, grails

reading the docs here:http://grails.org/plugin/jquery-ui

it says to use a custom theme I should put the theme at:

webapp/jquery-ui/themes/{theme-name}/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css

When I apply the tag in my main.gsp:

```
<jqui:resources theme="le-frog" />
```

Launch and Tomcat can't find the file. The tag seems to point to:

```
/myapp/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.10/jquery-ui/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css
```

Unless there's some magic going on (and I think there is) I can understand why this clearly doesn't work. If I point the browser directly to the file, i.e. put this in the address bar:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/jquery-ui/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css
```

Then it finds the file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: note that the default theme works fine. It's only when I point to a custom theme that it has problems.

Comment: Apparently I'm not the first person to run into this, unfortunately there's no answer on this thread either: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Not-able-to-make-a-simple-dialog-work-with-Grails-and-jquery-jquery-ui-plugins-td3053858.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line in the plugin source

JqueryUiTagLib.groovy line 113

```
url = g.resource(plugin:attrs.remove('plugin'), dir:attrs.remove('dir'), file:attrs.remove('file'))
```

If you remove the plugin attribute, the link is rendered correctly.  I *think* what the plugins should do is if the theme attribute to jqui:resource is present, it should leave that plugin attribute off the url generation (see line 113).  If the theme attribute is absent, load the default ui-lightness theme which comes with the plugin, which would require the plugin attribute.

Hope that makes sense.  Should probably submit a patch to the plugin creator or just let them know.

Comment: On a side note about this, I never use javascript plugins like this.  I generally load them from the CDN and just deal with the javascript myself vs going through a taglib.  What they give you is rarely worth the hassle.