# report bug against a grails plugin

Tags: grails-plugin

How do I report a bug against a grails plugin?

I asked this question, [grails + jquery ui plugin, using custom theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439776/grails-jquery-ui-plugin-using-custom-theme), to which I still haven't gotten an answer, and unfortunately I don't think one will be coming because someone else had the same problem here: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Not-able-to-make-a-simple-dialog-work-with-Grails-and-jquery-jquery-ui-plugins-td3053858.html and never got an answer either.

I went to the grails jquery-ui plugin page and there's no direct link for reporting a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Report bugs at http://jira.grails.org - and for this plugin use http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPJQUERYUI

You'll need to sign up for an account first.